# ErrorException [ Parse Error ]: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF

Tags: php, jquery, kohana, kohana-3

I want to validate or show the radio button checked,if some value is present in database. Please refer my views code,

```
<input type="radio" name="bothadvandlor"  value="1" <?php if($advs->is_checked == "1");?>checked="checked"<?php endif;?> class="advs"/> Show Google Ads<br/>
<input type="radio" name="bothadvandlor"  value="2" <?php if($advs->is_checked == "2");?>checked="checked"<?php endif;?> class="advs"/> Others
```

The above is the form i tried,but i am getting the syntax error message like "`ErrorException [ Parse Error ]: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF`" .

Need help to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use colon `:` instead of semi-colon `;` here after your `if` condition:

```
if($advs->is_checked == "1"):
// -----------------------  ^ here

if($advs->is_checked == "2"):
// -----------------------  ^ and here
```

From the **[docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)**:

> PHP offers an alternative syntax for some of its control structures;
>   namely, if, while, for, foreach, and switch. In each case, the basic
>   form of the alternate syntax is to change the opening brace to a colon
>   (:) and the closing brace to endif;, endwhile;, endfor;, endforeach;,
>   or endswitch;, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Should be colon `:`,

```
if($advs->is_checked == "1"):
                            ^
```

[*Reference*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="radio" name="bothadvandlor"  value="1" <?php if($advs->is_checked == "1"):?>checked="checked"<?php endif;?> class="advs"/> Show Google Ads<br/>
<input type="radio" name="bothadvandlor"  value="2" <?php if($advs->is_checked == "2"):?>checked="checked"<?php endif;?> class="advs"/> Others
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add that Kohana [has got some neat stuff for this](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Form#radio):

> public static radio( string $name [, string $value = NULL , boolean $checked = bool FALSE , array $attributes = NULL ] )

e.g.

```
<?php echo Form::radio('bothadvandlor', 1, ($advs->is_checked == '1'), array('class' => 'advs')); ?> Show Google Ads <br />
```

I think it makes these kinds of operations a whole lot easier. More separation of HTML and PHP thus better readability.